# How to calculate real average in JIDE pivot table?

Tags: java, swing, pivot-table, mean, jide

I found, that JIDE pivot table calculates average incorrectly.

If summaries contains averages too, then it computes average of averages, which is not the same value as total average (and just senseless value).

Is it possible to calculate true average in JIDE?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using `CalculatedPivotDataModel`, you can use the `CalculatedPivotDataModel.setRunningCalculateSummary(false)`call to achieve the desired behavior.

See the [api docs](http://www.jidesoft.com/javadoc/com/jidesoft/pivot/CalculatedPivotDataModel.html#setRunningCalculateSummary(boolean)) for more information.